# Is there a way to have Codeigniter automatically create a db with name specified in config file if it does not exist

Tags: mysqli, migration, codeigniter-3, php-7

I need to write migrations for **codeigniter**. But l don't want to create db manually. It will be perfect to create db automatically when I run the app at first time. Is there anyone who could help me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Hook in codeigniter. In hook you can use **pre_system** hoook. This will Call very early during system execution. For more details you can refer following link for hook in ci. [CI hook link](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/hooks.html)